# How can i rename the step in opencart 2.0

Tags: php, opencart

I am using opencart 2.0, and during the checkout i get options like

```
**Checkout**
Step 1: Checkout Options
Step 2: Billing Details   
Step 5: Payment Method 
Step 6: Confirm Order
```

How can i fix the order and display sequentially, or display something more appropriate and nice like tickmarks than displaying just steps and their no.

Comment: You have to edit the code :-)

Comment: Thanks, the question was which segment of code?

Comment: You have to go to the catalog/view/[theme-name]/template/checkout/ folder all files are related to checkout to the display are there and also use the corresponding language folder to edit text easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to rename, you will have to edit this file:

catalog/language/english/checkout/checkout.php

Change the values of these variables  (very easy):

```
$_['text_checkout_option']           = 'Step 1: Checkout Options';
$_['text_checkout_payment_address']  = 'Step 2: Billing Details';
$_['text_checkout_shipping_address'] = 'Step 3: Delivery Details';
$_['text_checkout_shipping_method']  = 'Step 4: Delivery Method';
$_['text_checkout_payment_method']   = 'Step 5: Payment Method';
$_['text_checkout_confirm']          = 'Step 6: Confirm Order';
```

for example:

```
   $_['text_checkout_option']           = 'First: Your text';
   $_['text_checkout_payment_address']  = 'Second....your text';
```

regards,

Comment: Thanks, this does help. I did made some changes in the view, that didn't helped me much, thanks for your advice, this has  solved the issue.

Comment: Great!, 
Now you should mark the correct answer!

Regards,